# How are unknown/invalid pseudo-classes in CSS selectors handled?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What does this CSS selector should point to? AFAIK :bar pseudo-class does not exist...

```
.Today_s_foo:bar
{
 font-size: 21px;
 font-family: "Ubuntu";
}
```

Comment: Why would it do anything, if it's invalid? Are you using some CSS-preprocessor (SASS, LESS, etc)?

Comment: @user2864740 : If something is not implemented in a browser, nothing would be applied. It's as good as applying styles to an element which does not exist.

Comment: I just got a PSD which has to be converted on HTML, I export the CSS to be applied by each element. The CSS has to be correct (or at least have some sense) as it comes from a kind of exam I have to do...

Comment: @biziclop I am not using any CSS-preprocessor, but may be they are suggesting to use it to solve the 'problem'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it should invalidate the whole rule, which may be important when using multiple selectors in one rule, see simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/S56xM/

HTML:

```
<div>Hello!</div>
```

CSS:

```
div, div:foobaresque { font-size: 100px; }
```

You will see that the `div { font-size: 100px; }` "sub-rule" is not applied, even if our mind tells us it would be applied.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [current specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#Conformance) for parsing errors in selectors: "the entire rule in which the selector is used is dropped." See also [this part of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) for an example of the consequences.

By "rule" it means every property setting inside the `{brackets}` will be ignored if any part of the selector is parsed as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Correction applied

**The rules in `.Today_s_foo` will not be set on any working browser.**

I thought it was listed as an Unrecommended hack on http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

IE

```
.Today_s_foo:IE6 /* IE6 hack */
```

but its not there.

Comment: I can't really find this specific hack on the linked page, only `body:empty`, `a:link:visited, a:visited:link`, but they are different.

Comment: so you mean they are like trying to bring me to some kind of error? I think I should not delete the :foo from the original CSS, but if I do not delete it the rule will not apply (well, only for < IE6)

Comment: @biziclop my mistake, I thought it was listed. user1249791 I'm not sure what browser would render that code at the moment. Their are better ways to send CSS to only one browser that do not create invalid "errors" in the CSS.